# set android:name of <fragment> programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

Is it possible to set the name of  added in XML layout from activity class, I need to make transition between fragments which are includes on the activity but only on  and replace the fragment name by new one.

```
 <fragment
        android:name="com.example.harry.comparateur_de_prix.Accueil.AccueilFragment" //To change
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment1">

    </fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `FrameLayout` instead here.

Then [use `FragmentTransaction`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) to replace that ViewGroup by its ID attribute

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to change your Activity's XML layout to include a FrameLayout like this:

```
<!--Other XML layout elements, view-groups, views etc...; other stuff-->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fl_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fl_height">
    </FrameLayout>
```

What we want to do now is; to be able to replace that FrameLayout in the Activity's XML layout above that we just added with the layout of one of your Fragment's layout file.

Now in your Activity file,

1. instantiate a FragmentManger object
2. obtain a fragmentTransaction instance via the fragmentManagers beginTransaction() method.

---

```
  /*1)*/  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  /*2)*/  FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

Then make these changes

```
ft.replace(R.id.id_1, new YourFragment());
ft.commit();
```

The argument YourFragment() will require you to insert an instance of one of your Fragments
, this will replace the FrameLayout's current layout with that of YourFragments(). We finally commit the fragmentTransaction.

---

If you want to replace the Fragment that the FrameLayout displays, simple begin a new fragment transaction and replace the frame layout with a new Fragment as shown above.